# Upload pictures to the server which resizes them and compresses, and finally sends the result to the origin CDN?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, xmlhttprequest, image-uploading

I'm having an app where users can have their gallery pictures.
 Now, I want to allow users to choose an image through an <input type="file">, then through an XHR/multiple XHRs, upload it to the server (a node.js server which uses express.js), which will resize the image to a custom size, and compress it(make out of it a 0.75-0.8 quality JPEG) and finally get rid of the image by sending it to the cdn origin.
In what ways can I achieve such a behaviour?
 And this an be done 'cause most modern websites use a similar approach. I just want to know what I need to do so..

Comment: By using php i guess?

Comment: he is using node/express as a backed. I guess no php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach:

Send the image via AJAX or POST to the server.

The server receives the image. As you are using Node.js, I found this [library](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/).

Process the image and send it back to the client

Why don't you post the codes that you have worked on so far?

Comment: There is no code since I have no idea how to process images server side, and the best way to send them to the server, whether through a base64 string or other ways. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Hmm, its a lot of work to do then. Start with sending posts here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/   Use this to send image from browser to your server. Once the post reaches the server, you need GET method to retrieve the image. Here is how you do GET in express: http://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/handle-get-post-request-express-4/  . Use imagemagick (the link I post above) to edit image, and post it back to the user. Needs some work actually.